# The starting "/" in the virtual path of the cache

Tags: caching, uri, g-wan

Pls clarify which one of the following is correct?
In the user's manual P.27, it is stated that:

> // note: **no starting ‘/’** in the virtual path
>      static char path[] = ”tools/counter.html”;  // a ‘virtual’ path 
>      int expire = 0; // 0:never

But in the header file of gwan.h, it is stated that:

> //create/update a cache entry ('file' MUST be imaginary if 'buf' is not NULL)
>   // cacheadd(argv, **"/tool/counter"**, buf, 1024, ".json", 200, 60); // expire:60sec
>   // cacheadd(argv, **"/archives/doc_1.pdf"**, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0); // never expire
>   //                             ('file' MUST exist if 'buf' is NULL)

Which one is correct, **with starting "/" or not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing at this discrepancy between the manual and the (older) header.

The proper notation is *without* a starting slash, as shown in the cache.c example of the G-WAN distribution:

```
   static char szpath[] = "cache1.html";
   int expire = 15;
   if(!cacheadd(argv, szpath, reply->ptr, reply->len, ".html", 200, expire))
   {
      printf("* error: could not add cache entry #1\n");
      return 503;
   }
```

The comment in the header file's comments will be updated. When in doubt, trying is probably the best way to check what works.